# How to use lambda/Stream api to filter distinct elements by object Attribute/Property

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of `Object`. Every object has a map with a key named "xyz". I want elements in the list which has unique value to that particular key.

I know we can do this easily with set/map but I'm particularly looking for lambda solution.

I thought this would work.

```
list.stream()
    .filter(distinctByXyz(f -> f.getMap.get("xyz")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I've a function to distinct them

```
private <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor){
    Map<Object, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> map.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

The problem is the function f.getMap() inside filter isnt working. Showing compilation error (Cannot resolve method)

Comment: you might have intended to do this: `list.stream().filter(f -> distinctByXyz(f.getMap.get("xyz"))).collect(Collectors.toList));`

Comment: And include parentheses for `Collectors#toList`!

Comment: What's the type of the objects in your list? Does the class of these objects implement the `getMap` method?

Comment: Besides, whenever you have a `Map<Whatever, Boolean>`, you can replace it by a `HashSet<Whatever>`

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  The problem could be as simple as `getMap` being a method rather than a member variable and so you would need parenthesis after it in your lambda.  Don't make us guess what the rest of your code says.

Comment: @Lino no - that is not not correct. Look at the `distinctByKey` method - it takes a `Function` and returns a `Predicate`... your solution will not even compile

Comment: @Eugene my bad I've misread the example, but the code in the question is, as already stated in your answer, not compiling because of multiple reasons so that may be why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a few typos in your code, this should work:

```
list
  .stream()
  .filter(distinctByKey(f -> f.getMap().get("xyz")))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You are using `distinctByXyz` when it should really be `distinctByKey`. Then `f.getMap` that should probably be `f.getMap()` and also you are slightly off with your parenthesis.